# extract attributes from pandas columns that satisfy a condition [sorted by frequency]

Tags: python, pandas, subset

So this is regarding [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61262719/extract-attributes-from-pandas-columns-that-satisfy-a-condition) I've posted on SO a while ago.

Going back to the beginning, here's the minimal example:

I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
tupl = [(0.1, 0.2, 0.7), (0,0,1), (0.2,0.6,0.2), (0.6,0.4,0)]

df_test = pd.DataFrame(tupl, columns = ["M1", "M2", "M3"], index =["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4"])
```

So it is a dataframe of frequencies of 3 different variables: M1, M2 and M3, over different instances: P1, ... P4.

Now for each row, I want to be able to extract as a string the occurrence of each variable, but, reversely to the previous question, **I would like to have it sorted by frequency**, such that the final output would be something like:

```
output = pd.DataFrame([("M3+M2+M1"), ("M3"), ("M2+M1+M3"), ("M1+M2")], 
                      columns = ["label"], index = ["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4"])
```

The previous answer was to do something such as:

```
(
    df_test.gt(0).apply(lambda x: np.where(x, x.name, None))
    .apply(lambda x: '+'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
    .to_frame('label') 
)
```

Which was great for my previous purpose, but now I need the labels pasted on the new table by frequency order. I've tried to solve this by passing it to a numpy, and then a loop over each row, but couldn't reach much success yet. I am wondering if there's a more pandonic or effective way of solving it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# sort values each row
obj1 = df_test.apply(lambda x: 
              sorted(x.items(), key=lambda y: y[-1], reverse=True)
              , axis=1)
# P1    [(M3, 0.7), (M2, 0.2), (M1, 0.1)]
# P2    [(M3, 1.0), (M1, 0.0), (M2, 0.0)]
# P3    [(M2, 0.6), (M1, 0.2), (M3, 0.2)]
# P4    [(M1, 0.6), (M2, 0.4), (M3, 0.0)]

# filter 0.0 & join with '+'
obj1.map(lambda x: [i[0] for i in x if i[-1] !=0]).str.join('+')
# P1    M3+M2+M1
# P2          M3
# P3    M2+M1+M3
# P4       M1+M2
# dtype: object
```

Comment: I've tried both solutions and they work perfectly! Thanks! I gave the accepted answer to Ferris because it is faster than jezrael's (278ms vs. 4.2s, respectively).

Comment: @jezrael the first one.

Comment: @LaCordillera - I try test solution and it was realy slow, so removed. I add timings and in sample data all 3 solution are faster like `Ferris` solution, is possible test with real data?

Answer (score 2):

I hope simplify and increasing performance in another solution should be used by one loop with generator comprehension with `join`:

```
f = lambda x: '+'.join(i for i,  j 
                      in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda y: y[-1], reverse=True) if j != 0)
df = df_test.apply(f, axis=1).to_frame('label')

print (df)
       label
P1  M3+M2+M1
P2        M3
P3  M2+M1+M3
P4     M1+M2
```

Another idea is use numpy with `np.argsort` for indices by sorted values with exclude `0` values, then also sorting mask and in list comprehension get output:

```
m = df_test.ne(0)
a = df_test[m].to_numpy()
c = df_test.columns.to_numpy()
ind = np.argsort(np.argsort(-a))

vals = c[ind]
mask = m.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df_test))[:, None], ind]

out = ['+'.join(i[j]) for i, j in zip(vals, mask)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'label':out}, index=df_test.index)
print (df)
       label
P1  M3+M2+M1
P2        M3
P3  M2+M1+M3
P4     M1+M2
```

Or use pandas only - replace `0` to `NaN`s, reshape for remove them, ascending sorting and grouping with `join`:

```
df = (df_test[df_test.ne(0)]
         .stack()
         .sort_values(ascending=False)
         .reset_index(level=1)
         .groupby(level=0)['level_1']
         .agg('+'.join)
         .to_frame('label')
         .reindex(df_test.index, fill_value=''))

print (df)
       label
P1  M3+M2+M1
P2        M3
P3  M2+M3+M1
P4     M1+M2
```

Performance in `40k rows`;

```
tupl = [(0.1, 0.2, 0.7), (0,0,1), (0.2,0.6,0.2), (0.6,0.4,0)]

df_test = pd.DataFrame(tupl, columns = ["M1", "M2", "M3"], index =["P1", "P2", "P3", "P4"])

#40 k rows
df_test = pd.concat([df_test] * 10000, ignore_index=True).rename(lambda x: f'P{x+1}')
print (df_test)
```

---

```
#Ferris solution 
In [59]: %%timeit
    ...: obj1 = df_test.apply(lambda x: 
    ...:               sorted(x.items(), key=lambda y: y[-1], reverse=True)
    ...:               , axis=1)
    ...: obj1.map(lambda x: [i[0] for i in x if i[-1] !=0]).str.join('+')
    ...: 
680 ms ± 6.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
In [63]: %%timeit
    ...: m = df_test.ne(0)
    ...: a = df_test[m].to_numpy()
    ...: c = df_test.columns.to_numpy()
    ...: ind = np.argsort(np.argsort(-a))
    ...: 
    ...: vals = c[ind]
    ...: mask = m.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df_test))[:, None], ind]
    ...: 
    ...: out = ['+'.join(i[j]) for i, j in zip(vals, mask)]
    ...: 
    ...: pd.DataFrame({'label':out}, index=df_test.index)
    ...: 
    ...: 
149 ms ± 1.53 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

```
In [60]: %%timeit

    ...: f = lambda x: '+'.join(i for i,  j 
                      in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda y: y[-1], reverse=True) if j != 0)
    ...: df_test.apply(f, axis=1).to_frame('label')
    ...: 
610 ms ± 8.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


In [66]: %%timeit
    ...: (df_test[df_test.ne(0)]
    ...:          .stack()
    ...:          .sort_values(ascending=False)
    ...:          .reset_index(level=1)
    ...:          .groupby(level=0)['level_1']
    ...:          .agg('+'.join)
    ...:          .to_frame('label')
    ...:          .reindex(df_test.index, fill_value=''))
    ...:          
477 ms ± 8.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```